# How do update UI when user presses the digital crown?

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

I have a user interface where the button should not appear when the WKInterfaceController is activated again.

I tried to hide the button in `willActivate`, in `willAppear`, and in `didDeactivate`.

But the button always appears briefly when the interface controller becomes active.

Is this due to watchOS taking a screenshot when the digital crown is pressed (similar as on an iPhone)?

What can I do so that the button does not appear for a brief moment when the interface controller is activated?

Comment: You have added the button in your interface storyboard?

Comment: Yes, and I've set it to hidden there.